# How to make vim automatically add a newline to the end of a file?

Tags: vimrc, save, line-breaks

Vim normally writes `<EOL>` for the last line only when there was one in the original file.

How to make vim to write a new line at the end of a file all the time (when the file is not binary and there isn't already one)?

I've tested `eol` option, but it didn't work as expected.

See also: [Preserve missing end-of-line at end of text files](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Preserve_missing_end-of-line_at_end_of_text_files), but opposite. And: [Why should files end with a newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/729692/55075)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### Basic info

Vim doesn't show latest newline in the buffer but actually vim always place EOL at the end of the file when you write it, because it standard for text files in Unix systems. You can find more information about this [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18743/whats-the-point-in-adding-a-new-line-to-the-end-of-a-file). In short you don't have to worry about the absence a new lines at the end of the file in vim.

#### Experiment 1

You can do this small experiment to check this behaviour. In the terminal execute:

```
$ vim test_test
```

Enter the character `1` and save the file <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>wq</kbd>.

You have only one character in the file, right? Actually no :) You now have in your file `1` and `LF` characters. Let's check it, with hexdump utility:

```
$ hexdump test_test
0000000 31 0a
0000002
```

`31` is ASCII code for character `1`, and `0a` is ASCII code for non-printing `LF` character which for the UNIX as you may already know code for end of line.

#### Experiment 2

But what if we will open file which don't have `eol` symbol at the end of the file. Let's check it too. Let's create file without eol at the end, for example like this:

```
$ echo -n "1" > test_without_eol
```

Then again let's look inside it with hexdump:

```
$ hexdump test_without_eol
000000 31
0000001
```

So there are no any `eol` characters here. Let's open this file in vim:

```
$ vim test_without_eol
```

At the bottom of editor you'll see:

```
"test_without_eol" [noeol] 1L, 1C
```

And if you'll save this file `eol` character will be putted automatically.

#### What we can do about this?

If you really need to see end of the file. Try to use this command:

```
:set listchars=eol:$
```

it will show all `eol` characters as `$` sign.

Comment: Great. I came to the same conclusion after my confusion, because Vim wasn't actually showing me this new line, but it was there after save.

Comment: @kenorb by the way you can show all EOL charachters using this comand `:set listchars=eol:$`

Comment: "wasn't actually showing me this new line" - in Unix, there is no line. A line is defined as "number of non-LF characters, terminating in a LF character".  If you think of LF not as "go to next line" but "end of line", what Vim does suddenly makes much more sense.

Answer (score 10):

Vim only omits the EOL if the file is opened as `'binary'` *and* the `'endofline'` option is reset (when the binary file didn't have an EOL when opening, or you explicitly reset the option). In other words, Vim only honors a missing EOL for binary files. **For text files, it always writes with an (added) EOL.** (That's why you need solutions like my [PreserveNoEOL plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4550) to keep text files without EOL.) You can find all the details at `:help 'endofline'`.

So, you only need to ensure to **open the file as non-binary** in order to have Vim automatically write an EOL.

Answer (score 5):

As [Alexander](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3304/467) mentioned, Vim doesn't show EOL at EOF, that's why it's so confusing (especially with [empty/blank new line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2287967/55075) which is another thing), therefore it actually writes every-time on file save.

Here is simple test how to test if that works:

```
$ printf foo > foo.txt
$ cat foo.txt
foo$ wc foo.txt
0 1 3 foo.txt
$ vim -cwq foo.txt
$ cat foo.txt
foo
$ wc foo.txt
1 1 4 foo.txt
```

Notice how shell prompt behave when there is no EOL (it goes mixed with the next line). When re-saving file with Vim, it adds it.

Using `wc` we can count lines, words and characters before saving and after, so we can see that it actually changes.

Why this is so important? To keep our files [POSIX compliant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/729692/55075).